# How to get exit status of program in fish shell

Tags: fish

In the bash shell, I could `echo $?` to get the exit code of a program run on the cli. What is the equivalent in the fish shell? Can't seem to find this in the docs.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

According to [the official Fish documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-exit-status-of-a-command), you can use the `$status` variable:

> #### How do I get the exit status of a command?
>
> Use the `$status` variable. This replaces the `$?` variable used in some other shells.